# ASP .NET MVC 3 - Submitting an Ajax form redirects instead of updating within page

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, scripting, unobtrusive-javascript, unobtrusive

I'm submitting an Ajax form but when it hits the controller the Request.IsAjax returns false and my page therefore redirects.  Anyone know why it would do this?

I have searched the internet and made sure that:

1. I have the following in my web.config under `<appSettings>`:

   `<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />`
2. I have the following scripts in my page at runtime from viewing the source:

   ```
   <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js" type="text/javascript" />

   <script src="/Scripts/modernizr-1.7.min.js" type="text/javascript" />

   <script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.11.min.js" type="text/javascript" />

   <script src="/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js" type="text/javascript" />

   <script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript" />

   <script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js" type="text/javascript" />
   ```

Not sure if this is a red herring but I'll mention it because I've hit a brick wall here - when I do view source in Google Chrome only the first script has it's colours formatted, which makes me think I haven't got the syntax right - but it looks right to me!
Help!

Comment: can you post the AjaxForm code

Comment: Sure, here it is so far:

`<form 
    action="/Item/TestAjaxMethod" 
    data-ajax="true" 
    data-ajax-mode="replace" 
    data-ajax-update="#filter-results" 
    id="form0" 
    method="post">

    <select id="myId" name="MyItem" onchange="submit()">
        <option selected="selected">Option 1</option>
        <option>Option 2</option>
        <option>Option 3</option>
    </select>
</form>`

Comment: I should mention that my @Ajax.ActionLinks on the same controller work correctly, so the scripts must be OK.  Must be something else...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is how I am submitting the form.  I was just doing an `onchange="submit()"` in a dropdown list.

I've now realised that a javascript submit like that is not the same as an ajax submit!  :)

If I use an `<input type="submit" />` it works.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure your script refs are above your Ajax call. Load up fiddler and ensure the jquery scripts are found and load.

Comment: They are found, and they do load. 

My scripts are not above my Ajax call - they are at the bottom of the page just before the closing body tag.  Could this be the problem?  I read somewhere that this is the recommended approach and may improve performance.

Comment: Just tried it, no luck.. in fact my Ajax.Actionlink calls are working, so the scripts must be OK.